# git don't overwrite old commits but push new project folder

Tags: git, github

my react-native project was broken so I created a new folder and copyed all files to the new folder and reinstalled all packages. The project now works again and I would like to commit it to github.

But how do I commit these new changes without first pulling the old state and without overwriting the old commits?

I hope it's clear what I mean
thank you for your time!

Comment: If you built the new version on top of the old version you shouldn't need to make any changes to be able to push to a remote, unless you amended a previously pushed commit. If you did you will need to either force push (which will overwrite the remote's history which isn't ideal), clean up the amended commit

Comment: the old project was completly broken and I just made a new folder. Could it work to just copy over the git folder?

Comment: ooooh i misunderstood. I mean technically i think you could, but it would be better to just delete the contents in the original project and copy the new project files over to avoid having a messy "merge" when just copying the `.git` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what @joshmeranda suggested in the comments, this is what I would do:

1. Delete old broken files
2. Commit deleting them
3. Copy new files to old project/folder
4. Commit
5. force-push your local changes to your remote

If you commit deleting old files and "creating" (copying) new files you should have a clean git history of what you did. After force pushing you should still be able to go back a few commits to your old changes.

Please do correct me if I'm wrong about this!